# How to fly a parabolic arc?

Tags: flight-controls, pilot-technique

The title says it all, how do you fly a parabolic arc? Me and my friend Ben, are starting a research lab. We want to learn how to fly a parabolic arc.

Comment: With what? Do you mean vertically, or laterally?

Comment: Have a flight instructor show you.  You don't need a G-meter - a 12" piece of yarn tied somewhere convenient inside the cockpit will do.

Comment: The Vomit Comet enters the procedure at 360 kts and pitches up to 46°. At the top of the arc they pitch down 46* and level off at the starting altitude. Repeat 30-40 times. https://www.nasa.gov/missions/research/kc135.html

Comment: It's quite simple; I used to do it with my children, although it was a very small arc. I'd put something small and light (so it wouldn' hurt anybody if it hit them) on the top of the glareshield. Then bring the nose up to an attitude that would stall it if you kept it there, but well before the stall, push over until whatever you put on the glareshield floats. It takes a bit of practice to keep it floated in the same position for a few seconds. As the nose comes down through level, pull the power. Then you need to stop the arc and start the nose up again well before you hit Vne.

Comment: @Terry Ever tried Bob Hoover's tea pouring trick?

Comment: @TomMcW No, I was never that good, not even close. There are those whose performance for whatever reason, natural ability, experience, whatever, is simply phenomenal. He was one.

Answer (score 1):

Get lots of airspeed,pitch up within ac flight envelope limits and as you approach stall speed for your configuration, push forward so that 0 G is shown on the g meter, and keep it there.
As you come over the top pull out again within it's so you neo not exceed Vne,Vmo or Mmo or g limit's for your planes . A parabola for a few minutes or second depending on the plane.

Comment: A few minutes?!  Two minutes of zero G will have you go from sea level to FL580 and back, and requires an initial vertical speed of 115750 feet per minute (1140 knots)! I guess it depends indeed on the plane, but to stay realistic I would not go beyond half a minute.

Comment: If you consider the Virgin Galactic hybrid aircrfat, spaceship  as an extreme case, I believe that they are advertising 4 minutes of weightless ness, but I concede that most aircraft are limited to far less. I do it for several seconds weightless ness in a glider showing pupils how, even when flying below stall speed the aircraft is both controllable... If sluggish, and definitely not stalled.

Answer (score 1):

Pull the nose up, take out a pencil and hold it in front of your face, and then let go of it and keep it floating in front of your face by judicious use of the throttle and stick (yoke).

Obviously, you will end up in a dive, and airspeed will increase dramatically. If you approach Vne, or if the throttle reaches idle to keep the pencil from moving forward in the cockpit, you need to stop and recover. The higher your nose, and airspeed, the longer you will be able to do this before the nose gets so low that you must grab the pencil and cease the maneuver, and recover from the dive to avoid over-speeding the aircraft.